# How to count other posts not having specific taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, count

I have a custom post type "book", and a taxonomy "language" with terms "php" , "java" ,"c", "python".
I want to count "book" posts not having terms "java" & "c"..
such that posts with only "java" or "c" should be counted but posts with both "java" and "c" should not be counted.
I tried tax_query of WP_QUERY using operator "NOT IN" and "=" but haven't got correct answer.
There should be "NAND" operator for tax_query.

*P.S : I have approx 20 terms and 200 posts for each. With this tax_query I have added 1 AND tax_query also and that is for other taxonomy term.*

`$myargs=array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'ABC', 'XYZ' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( "c", "java"),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
'post_type' => 'book');`

A book may have one or more language terms.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a `NAND` operator for the [`tax_query` of `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). If I understood correctly, what you intend can be rewritten this way:

1. Get all the posts without the term `c`.
2. Get all the posts without the term `java`.
3. Exclude the posts having both the terms `c` and `java`.

To achieve that, you can combine two `NOT IN` queries and match them with an `OR`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'c' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'java' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    )            
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

echo count( $posts );
```

Comment: Thanx for this but, I have approx 20 terms and 200 posts for each so this should not be a good way to get correct answer.

Comment: May I ask why not? It runs a single and fairly simple SQL query achieving the desired result. If you intend to do some other kind of queries, please, update the question with as much details as possible. Otherwise it's impossible for us to know beforehand.

Comment: If I want 17 different combinations, I need to write 17 `NOT IN` arrays  for each i.e total 289 `NOT IN` arrays in tax_query. Can you please provide a better way for this? Sometimes the question requires editing even after it gets an answer. It happens.

Comment: With those requirements, I won't expect a simple solution. But let's wait then for other users to come with different approachs. Tomorrow you will probably get more answers.

Comment: I think you will do better producing a single $posts array and then using a function to iterate over its contents to produce the count contextually, rather than (apparently) through a relatively large number of separate db queries. However, it's not clear what you want on the output side. At one point it appears that you have particular exclusions in mind, but at another point it seems that you're interested in books that treat one language only, and have no use for ones that have two or more. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: I'm interested in book that treats `ALL` specific terms of list instead of `ANY` term from the list.

Comment: Not following at all, as that seems to be the opposite of your initial question, which seemed to be an ask for book posts with one language only: Once you have the get_posts() array, identifying which book posts had one and only one specific language, language by language, would be a very straightforward PHP operation. Maybe if you provided an output example, with enough in it to nail down what you were trying to achieve (and showing what you were NOT trying to achieve)...

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys somehow this helped me to get count of NAND operation.
Because I dont need ti iterate through those posts, I used `found_posts` of `WP_Query` . Subtracting my posts count from total post count.

I'm still waiting for a better way if any. Thanx [Luis](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/233688/86197).

```
$myargs=array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  $author_terms //array of author term slug(s),
            'operator' => 'IN'  //default operator ?

        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $language_terms //array of language term slug(s)
            'operator' => 'AND' 
        )
    ),
'post_type' => 'apk');

$allargs=array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  $author_terms //array of author term slug(s),
            'operator' => 'IN'  //default operator ?

        )
    ),
'post_type' => 'apk');

$myquery=new WP_Query($myargs);
$allquery=new WP_Query($allargs);

echo allquery->found_posts - $myquery->found_posts;
```